# Triple integral: How do I include assumptions and conditions?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions

I would like to solve the following integral:
$$I=\int_{0}^{a} \int_{0}^{y} \int_{0}^{z} e^{(a-x)^{3}} d x d z d y$$
with the condition that:
$$a>0$$
So I tried to input the equation like below into Mathematica, but I get error messages saying Assumptions could help.

[image]

Then I tried to do it like this but no to avail:
[image]

What am I doing wrong? Are the inputs I have mathematically incomplete, or am I doing a mistake in formatting them in Mathematica, or both??

Edit: I tried to copy the code, I hope I could do it right:

```
\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(a\)]\(\((
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(y\)]\((
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(z\)]
\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), 
SuperscriptBox[\((a - 
            x)\), \(3\)]] \[DifferentialD]x)\) \[DifferentialD]z)\) \
\[DifferentialD]y\)\)
```

The second one:

```
Integrate[(\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(y\)]\(\((
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(z\)]
\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), 
SuperscriptBox[\((a - 
           x)\), \(3\)]] \[DifferentialD]x)\) \[DifferentialD]z\)\)), \
{y, 0, a}, Assumptions -> {a > 0 && y \[Element] Reals}]
```

In input-converted form:

```
Integrate[
 Integrate[Integrate[E^(a - x)^3, {x, 0, z}], {z, 0, y}], {y, 0, a}]
```

The second equation:

```
Integrate[
 Integrate[Integrate[E^(a - x)^3, {x, 0, z}], {z, 0, y}], {y, 0, a}, 
 Assumptions -> {a > 0 && Element[y, Reals]}]
```

Comment: Please post *Mathematica* code as text rather than as images. That will help us diagnose your problem better.

Comment: I did it, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Also please convert your cells to InputForm prior to copy and paste.

Comment: I believe I did that, I inserted the InputForm equations as well.

Comment: This is a repeated integral that can be transformed to a 1d integral (I think)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use a single call to [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate):

```
Integrate[Exp[(a - x)^3], {y, 0, a}, {z, 0, y}, {x, 0, z}]
```

> Integrate[-(a*ExpIntegralE[2/3, -a^3]) + (a - z)*ExpIntegralE[2/3, -(a - z)^3],
> {y, 0, a}, {z, 0, y}]/3

However, it seems that Mathematica can only partially do this integral as written (note that this was evaluated in Mathematica 12.3, in earlier versions an incorrect result was returned). An alternative is to make use of [`Region`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Region) functionality. The region of integration is:

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[0 < y < a && 0 < x < z && 0 < z < y, {x, y, z}];
```

Using this region in [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate):

```
sol = Integrate[Exp[(a-x)^3], {x, y, z} ∈ reg, Assumptions -> a > 0]
```

> 1/6 (-1 + E^a^3)

Let's use NIntegrate to check for a numerical value of `a`:

```
NIntegrate[Exp[(3 - x)^3], {y, 0, 3}, {z, 0, y}, {x, 0, z}]
N[sol /. a->3]
```

> 8.86747*10^10

> 8.86747*10^10

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in using the same variable name (e.g., $y$) for the variable of integration *AND* the integration limit.

A no-no.

This works:

```
    Assuming[a > 0 && {a, y, z} \[Element] Reals,
 Integrate[E^(a - x)^3, {x, 0, z}, {z, 0, y}, {y, 0, a}]]
```

Incidentally, you might just perform the trivial $y$ and $z$ integrals separately.

Comment: `Assuming[a > 0,
 Integrate[Exp[(a - x)^3], {x, 0, a}, {y, 0, y}, {z, 0, z}]]
` also works..

Comment: Your integration is still different from the OP's.